Convert DOC Files to PDF Using AWS Glue Python Job?
I am trying to convert a list of DOC files to PDF using an AWS Glue Python job. The DOC files are stored in S3, and I want to store the converted PDF files back in S3. The DOC files may contain plain text, images, tables, etc.
I have found several articles on performing this using AWS Lambda, but I haven't found any useful resources for doing it with AWS Glue.
Has anyone successfully implemented DOC to PDF conversion in an AWS Glue job?
This is the command working fine in the terminal. the issue I am facing in the Python job is using the libraoffice dependency.
command ["libreoffice7.6","--headless","--convert-to","pdf","input_path","output_path"]


The code wouldn't be different that what you experimented in AWS Lambda. The only thing is that when you use additional packages to do they conversion you need to specify it in the glue job configuration as an additional package.
